# CodeIgniter uploading files no file

Tags: php, codeigniter

Ok try to upload file for hours but i get error,

```
You did not select a file to upload.
```

my code is in CI

```
 $this->config =  array(
                  'upload_path'     => dirname($_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"])."/uploads/",
                  'upload_url'      => base_url()."uploads/",
                  'allowed_types'   => "gif|jpg|png|jpeg|pdf|doc|xml",
                  'overwrite'       => TRUE,
                  'max_size'        => "1000KB",
                  'max_height'      => "768",
                  'max_width'       => "1024"  
                );

             $this->load->library('upload', $this->config);
            if($this->upload->do_upload('logo'))
            {
                echo "file upload success";
            }
            else
            {
               echo $this->upload->display_errors();
            }
```

in view i have

```
<input type="file" name="logo"/>
```

when i print_r $_POST i get

```
Array ( [name_srpski] => tyre [name_english] => Client nametre [logo] => cipele-plava_1.jpg )
```

Where could be error its very important

Comment: [I think you need to read the documentation again](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html).  I can spot at least two mistakes in your configuration array just by quickly glancing.   Have you tried  `$this->upload->display_errors()` to see what it reports?

Comment: According to the docs, there is no such option called `upload_url`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try changing  `$this->load->library('upload', $this->config);` to

```
 $this->load->library('upload');
 $this->upload->initialize( $this->config );
```

Also the form type should be multipart

```
<form method="post" action="some_action" enctype="multipart/form-data" />
```

Comment: He is allowed to use `$this->load->library('upload', $this->config)` as per the code examples in the docs:  https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html

Comment: Why the down vote? It was most likely the multipart type that was causing him a bit of trouble. 

And yes I think a lot of people are aware that the manual exists. It was a suggestion since what he had was not working. You never know, most people who ask around in SO often paste code that are not necessarily what they actually have.

Comment: Read my comment again.  There is nothing wrong with using `$this->load->library('upload', $this->config)` and I linked to the docs to support this assertion, not to tell you where to find the docs.  Remove the first half of your answer and see if the down-voter re-evaluates.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following in config:

```
'upload_path'     => FCPATH . "/uploads/", // or use "./uploads/" instead
'max_size'        => "1000", // remove the kb from the string. it requires only the number
```

Comment: I also see no such option called `upload_url` in the docs.  https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html

Comment: true! that's why I removed it

Comment: So how is anyone reading this supposed to know that `upload_url` is not a valid option when you also "removed" valid options like `overwrite`, `max_width`, etc?

Comment: what do you mean??? upload_url there's not such an option available. the others you can put them if you want

Comment: What I mean is that the OP is using a non-existant option called `upload_url` and you failed to point that out as an invalid line of code.